# How to query Json(without key value) in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am currently on a project in which there is a requirement to store skills attribute

```
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)

@Type(type = "json")
@Column(columnDefinition = "json")
private List<String> skills;
```

into a text data type in Postgres (but this will be saved as a valid JSON). This is achieved using the link https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-collections-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

The sample data that fills this attribute is as follow

```
.skills(asList(
            "Java".concat(String.valueOf(i)), 
            "Python".concat(String.valueOf(i)),
            "DotNet".concat(String.valueOf(i))))
```

value in data base that is stored is `["Java9","Python9","DotNet9"]`.
I know this is not the right way to do this job, but i just want to know that if there is any way to query in JPA that i can use native JPA function to retrieve `Java9` from the skills attribute. Or even can i write a SQL query that can return this data to me. I know there how to retrieve data from JSON object that has key value pairs as of the following link 'https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/' but this does not apply in my case since my JSON (sort of) does not have a key value pairs.

In addition, if I keep the data type in PG as Text, then it allows to insert the record, if we change the data type to JSON, then it throws exception.

Problem statement: is there any way i can query a text (as JSON) in a comma separated list of values (skills in this specific case). Appreciate for looking into it.

Comment: "*if we change the data type to JSON, then it throws exception*" then whatever you think is a valid JSON value, isn't

Comment: In plain SQL, you could use the `@>`, `?`, `?|` or `?&` operators to test for elements in an array.

Answer (score 0):

If the values are stored as array in a `json` field in postgresql >= 9.4, you can access them as text by their index using the `->>` operator (see [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html)).

So, if your data is e.g. in `mytable` as follows (`val` being a column of type `json`)

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["Java9", "Python9", "DotNet9"] |

then the statement

```
SELECT val->>0 as val
  FROM mytable
 WHERE id = 1
```

would return

| val |
| --- |
| Java9 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=257c293187be5704d3c90983e3ca9613) for a full example.